# Visualforce dynamic components issue

Tags: visualforce

I have this page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="contact" extensions="dyanmicvfcontroller" >
 <apex:form >
 <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!comp1}"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and controller

```
public class dyanmicvfcontroller {
public component.apex.sectionheader comp1{get;set;}
//public component.apex.selectlist comp2{get;set;}
    public dyanmicvfcontroller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {   
    date duedateset = date.newinstance(2011,7,9);
    boolean overdue = date.today().daysbetween(duedateset)>0;
    comp1 = new component.apex.sectionheader();
//comp2 = new component.apex.selectlist(multiselect=false);
    if(overdue)
    comp1.title = 'OVERDUE';
    else
    comp1.title ='NOTOVERDUE';
    }
}
```

When i include  in my page this will give a run time exception

> System.SerializationException: Not Serializable:
>   Component.apex.sectionheader

without apex:form on page,section header is displayed

Even if sectionheader component is oustide apex:form ,it gives exception

Whats happening here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it is trying to serialize the component.apex.sectionheader() to be  part of the view state.  It doesn't actually have to be inside the form tags for it to be a part of the view state.

When the form is not on the page the error goes away because there is no view state. I can think of a couple of things off the top of my head that you might be able to do, depending on your use case.

1. You could refactor the page to not use the form. Depending on what it is that you are collecting perhaps you could use JavaScript Remoting.
2. You could make comp1 transient.
3. You could remove the comp1 property and supply a getComp1() method that constructs and returns the component without storing it in a property.

Comment: thanks..is it that only certain components cannot be serialised?

Comment: I'm not sure. I suspect that it is either all or nothing. There is a [Component class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_dynamic_components.htm) and I don't see any mention of Serializable there.